# how to display configurable image in wishlist sidebar

Tags: php, magento

today I'm fighting with Magento again :) 
how to display configurable image in wishlist sidebar
I use the code

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); ?>
    <?php $_product->load($_product->getIdBySku($_item['sku'])); ?>

<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(70, 87); ?>" />
```

but is not working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<?php
if($_product->getTypeId()=='simple'){
    $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
    ->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId());
    $parentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]);    
?>
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($parentProduct, 'small_image')->resize(70, 87); ?>" />
<?php }else{ ?>
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(70, 87); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```